# Read file from txt using 2d vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Is it possible to use the operator [] in case of 2d vectors? For example i got the following code:

```
vector<vector<string>> data;

ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("stoixeia_astheni.txt");


while (!myReadFile.eof()) {

    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            myReadFile  >> data[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

I got message out of range. I have a file with 5 lines and 4 columns.

Comment: Are you allocating the right length for your vectors, or at least resizing them to the appropriate sizes?

Comment: @Fere You can have any number (within reason I presume) of vectors inside each other, but in regards to performance and readability, it's kinda sketchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vector `data` is empty, its `size()` is 0. You have to `resize` it first or add new elements by using `push_back()`:

```
while (!myReadFile.eof()) {    
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        vector<string> tmpVec;
        string tmpString

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            myReadFile  >> tmpString;
            tmpVec.push_back(tmpString);
        }
        data.push_bac(tmpVec);
    }
}
```

You could also set the size right at the declaration of `data`:

```
vector<vector<string>> data(5,vector<string>(4));

ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("stoixeia_astheni.txt");

while (!myReadFile.eof()) {

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            myReadFile  >> data[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for very well explained answer and two examples showing possible solutions.

Comment: Zeta i tried to do something like the arraylists in java. Thanks anyway very useful answer.

Comment: @zeta Very low, or non-existant? Regardless, I gave my +1 as compensation either way.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``i < 5`` in the first solution?