# inserting txt file values into multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

i need some help inserting a series of values into a vector.
For example my .txt file looks something like this;

```
0
0
35
0
2
0
35
0
0
0
2
0
etc.
```

I need to insert these values into a 2D vector. ie. if the table is to be 10x5 it would look like;

```
0 0 35 0  2
0 2 0  35 0
0 0 2  0  etc.
```

i would like to use something like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> Pix;

vector<int> tmp_col;
int i;
int j;

for (i=0; i<largeur; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<hauteur; j++) {

    }
}
```

but i dont know how or wether to use a push.back function or get.line (i am very new to programming)

Thank you for any help :)))

Comment: Possible duplication: [Read file from txt using 2d vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939867/read-file-from-txt-using-2d-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions and the values in the text file are always separated by white space, which includes newlines, you can do the following:

```
vector<vector<int>> Pix(height, vector<int>(width));

for (auto& y : Pix)
{
    for (auto& x : y)
    {
        if (! (mystream >> x))
        {
            // failure to parse
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the vectors should be indexed as `Pix[y][x]`

Comment: thanks. Will this allow the vector to change size as there will be hundreds of values going into it. I already know the final size of the vector.

Comment: @JamesRushbrooke I'm not sure what you mean. Here the vectors are set the final size at the beginning. I assumed the final size is known?

Comment: yes the final size is known, i just dont understand how each value will go into the vector in the right position, considering they must be at the right height and width placement. Im sorry if my questions dont make sense, i am very new to all this @NeilKirk

Comment: Do you understand the for loops? The first puts every row vector in `y`, and then the second puts every element of the row vector into `x`. It will query the vector's current size, in this case `width`, to know how many elements should be processed in `x` per row.

Comment: ok great... and the if condition...i dont quite understand what it does and what i should put in the //failure to parse section. thank you again

Comment: The if statement will trigger if it fails to read an int from the file. Perhaps you have reached the end of the file, or there was a letter instead of a number. What to do is up to you. You could print an error message and close the program.